# Jquery show text of back-to-back divs in a loop

Tags: jquery

For example I have below div classes

```
<div class="info_title">title 1</div>
<div class="info_message">message 1</div>
<div class="info_title">title 2</div>
<div class="info_message">message 2</div>
<div class="info_title">title 3</div>
<div class="info_message">message 3</div>
```

I want loop through each of the *info_title* class and show its text. However I want to show the text of corresponding div with *info_message* class in the same loop as well. Below code is how I'm trying to do it.

```
if ($(".info_title").length) {
   $( ".info_title" ).each(function( i ) {
          alert($( this ).text());
          // alert('info message');
    });
}
```

How can I do it properly?

Comment: `alert($( this ).next().text());`

Answer (score 0):

It's shaky because it is dependent on your current structure but you can try [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) which will allow you to select the element immediately *before* the selected element in the DOM:

```
$('.info_messages').each(function(i, ele) {
    var $msg = $(ele);
    alert($msg.text()); //.info_messages text

    var $title = $msg.prev('.info_title');
    if ($title.length) { //Only alert title text if it exists
         alert($title.text()); //.info_title text
    }
});
```